# how to create a custom form who store data in wordpress and display in admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a task where my client is required a long contact form with multiple and different fields and the real task is to obtain the data from user and store in wordpress and display this data in wordpress admin panel where my client is able to see data or even filter.

please friends if you know any tutorial related to my subject. please let me know.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to go with plugins always, try to create your own, that is good for your practice and more flexible to your custom requirements.

Here is a simple tutorial for you,

http://kvcodes.com/2014/06/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-wordpress-without-using-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at User data plugins?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extra-user-details/

In my opinion you'll be best off creating a custom plugin for WordPress http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin, Use PHP to query the database for the users information filters you select on the admin panel. This should be simple but effective.